# Virtual keycode for key 2 (small, just on top of tab key)

Tags: virtual, keycode

I'm looking for a way to be able to capture the key shown in the photo below: On a French keyboard, it's the key that only has the character 2 (small).
[Key 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bTLG.png)
I first tried to use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key but it annoyed users:
Hotkey.registerHotkey (Me, 27, Hotkey.KeyModifier.None)
I then tried to use the <kbd>End</kbd> key but it does not always work:
Hotkey.registerHotkey (Me, 35, Hotkey.KeyModifier.None)

Could you tell me what the code would be for that key 2 please ?

I don't recognize it on the Microsoft website :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Comment: Maybe try https://keycode.info/ to see if that helps identify the keycode.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It's `222`. I used KeyboardStateView.exe.